# Is salesforce provide any REST API's to access visualforce page?

Tags: rest, salesforce, apex

I have created simple VisualForce page TestPage.vfp. I can access this in broswer using **https://ap5.salesforce.com/apex/TestPage** . Is there any REST API which salesforce exposes to call from Postman. I can see REST API services on this path /services/data/vXX.0 (xx version number). I'm able to use Postman to login to salesforce and perform query operation on objects. Similarly is there any REST API available to access visualforce page. Looked at workbench also and there also I can not see any REST API's to access VF page.

Found some links, the explanation says we will not be able to access VF page directly using Postman.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000099xUIAQ

http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/using-curl-with-salesforce-rest-api/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to expose a URL as an Apex REST API you will need to create the following:

1. Add a Domain (My Domain)
2. A site to host the REST API
3. Apex REST API class
4. Apex test class

Create a Rest API with this template:

```
@RestResource( urlMapping = '/mySpecialRest/*' )
global with sharing class MySpecialRestResource
{

    @HttpGet
    global static void doGet()
    {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        res.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        try {

            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize( mySpecialResponse ));
            return;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            res.statusCode = 400;
            Map<String, Object> responseMap = new Map<String, Object> {
                    'status'            => 'Failure',
                    'typeName'          => e.getTypeName(),
                    'message'           => e.getMessage(),
                    'stackTraceString'  => e.getStackTraceString()
            };
            res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(responseMap));
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

Then create the site and add the Rest API Class to the Public Profile:

`Setup > Sites > Site > Public Access Settings > Enabled Apex Class Access`

Or don't, depends on how you want to serve it?

Then call the the REST API via Postman with:

```
https://<My Domain>.<Salesforce Instance>.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/mySpecialRest
```

If the REST service is not public remember to authenticate by adding the Authorization header.

Comment: is it possible to write a Rest API so that it will return the whole visualforce page as HTML content, along with css and js references. Here my requirement is when I call Rest API it should return HTML content and if save that html and open in browser that look should exactly same as if we open the visualforce page link in browser.

Comment: That is not a Rest API, that would just be exposing the VF page through a public site.